# Does not show the new data after change has been made

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a search feature for my webpage so that it can update the information. When I search the record and update the information. Then go back to search the record again the original information is showing. I check the MySQL database and it does indeed show that the information is change not sure why this is happening. Anyone run into this problem before?

Here is my index.php form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title></title>
    <meta content="IE=9" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <link href="css/style01.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Inventory Integrity Edit Request
    Form</h2><br>
    <br>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="mainContent">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="get">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id">Enter
                    Request ID #</label>

                    <div class="input-group col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" id="id" name="=id"
                        placeholder="Type the id" type="text"> <span class=
                        "input-group-btn"><button class=
                        "btn btn-default btnSearch" type="button"><span class=
                        "input-group-btn"><span class=
                        "input-group-btn"><span class=
                        "input-group-btn"><span class=
                        "input-group-btn"><span class=
                        "input-group-btn"><span class=
                        "glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</span></span></span></span></span></span></button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <!-- This table is where the data is display. -->

                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id=
                "resultTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>

                            <th>Name</th>

                            <th>lanId</th>

                            <th>Department</th>

                            <th>Manager</th>

                            <th>Work Requested</th>

                            <th>PO</th>

                            <th>IS</th>

                            <th>Request Comments</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                makeAjaxRequest();
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                makeAjaxRequest();
                return false;
            });

            function makeAjaxRequest() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/search.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {id: $('input#id').val()},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my search.php form

```
<?php

    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $OK = true; // We use this to verify the status of the update.
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        // Create the query
        $data = "%".$_GET['id']."%";
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id like ?';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $results = $stmt->execute(array($data));
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
        //echo $error[2];
    }
    // If there are no records.
    if(empty($rows)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='4'>There were not records</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
                $id = $row['id'];
                echo "<td><a href='update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['lanId']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['department']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['mgrname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['work_requested']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['purchase_order']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['inbound_shipment']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['request_comments']."</td>";


            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disable ajax caching:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/search.php',
    cache: false,
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        id: $('input#id').val()
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
    }
});
```

**edit:** from the `jQuery` API documentation for `jQuery.ajax()`:

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')

Comment: Thank you sir that worked I didn't know ajax caching was enabled by default.

Comment: I will accept your answer once I can it says 6 min to accept.

Comment: you are welcome! and i wasn't sure that's it's turned on by default either, but your problem very much sounded like a caching problem.